# Возможно ли снизить вес exe файла при компиляции через нуитку?

Tags: python, nuitka

Написал программу. Упаковал её в exe файл с параметром onefile. Всё ок, работает как надо, но сам exe файл весит 40 мб, хотя в самом скрипте я не использовал сторонних модулей, да и встроенные модули только не тяжёлые использовал. Стало интересно, возможно ли снизить вес итогового файла, или это естественный размер? Лично мне кажется, что программа которая через requests отсылает пару запросов на сервер и сортирует их не должна столько весить, хотя, возможно, я чего-то в этом не понимаю.

Comment: Вместе с вашей программой в *.exe запаковывается интерпретатор Python.

Comment: @AlTheOne насколько я знаю, нуитка переводит всё в си код, а он не так прожорлив по памяти

Comment: Это логично, ведь и сам интерпретатор на Си написан.

Comment: @AlTheOne ладно, понял, спасибо за ответ